# How do you send an authorization header to a REST API from the copy task of an azure data factory pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create an Azure data factory to copy data from an API to blob storage.  The problem I'm encountering is getting the authorization to work.  The API requires a token whose value we already have.  The curl for the API is:

```
curl -X GET "https://zentracloud.com/api/v3/get_env_model_data/?device_sn=<value>&model_type=<value>&port_num=<value>
&inputs=<value>" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Authorization: Token <token>"
```

I've tried putting the Authorization into the auth headers of the Linked Service[image: Linked service properties]

and in the additional headers of the source of the Copy Data task[image: copy data source settings]

When I click "Preview Data" I get an "invalid credentials" error, which tells me either I'm not putting the authentication headers in the right place or my format is incorrect.  I'm not sure how to get this thing to work.

Comment: Can you try adding **Bearer** before your token? like "Authorization": "Bearer (your token)"

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT: I can try that, but I was under the impression that this API wanted things in the form "Token <token>"

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT: I was hoping that would be it, but I'm still getting "invalid credentials".  Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Microsoft and was told that they don't support validation via a token.